# Animation when grid columns layout data change

Tags: sapui5

Have a look at the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/MigfbB7oQ5dWMW0IAdS7?p=preview

I have defined 3 items in a SAPUI5 Grid and assigned them the values like this so that they occupy an entire row:

```
            <VBox id="vBoxCol1" class="column">
                <html:div>
                    COL 1
                </html:div>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L8 M8 S12" />
                </layoutData>
            </VBox>

            <VBox id="vBoxCol2" class="column">
                <html:div>
                    COL 2
                </html:div>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12" />
                </layoutData>
            </VBox>

            <VBox id="vBoxCol3" class="column">
                <html:div>
                    COL 3
                </html:div>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S12" />
                </layoutData>
            </VBox>
```

Dynamically I want to change the expanded column

```
 this.byId("vBoxCol2").addDelegate({
  onclick: jQuery.proxy(function() {
    this.expandColumn("center");
  }, this)

});

expandColumn: function(column) {
switch (column) {
  case "left":
    this.byId("vBoxCol1").setLayoutData(new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
      span: "L8 M8 S12"
    }));
    this.byId("vBoxCol2").setLayoutData(new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
      span: "L2 M2 S12"
    }));
    this.byId("vBoxCol3").setLayoutData(new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
      span: "L2 M2 S12"
    }));
    break;
.........
```

Everything works as  expected. The question now is how do I attach an animation for width? so that expanding/collapsing can have a smooth transition.

I tried adding this but does not work:

```
.column{
border: 1px solid #895;
-webkit-transition: 2s;
transition: 2s;
```

}

It works only if I set the width of the columns through css classes, but it does not fit in here as I need to change the LayoutData programatically.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Quite a good question. I already tried to set the style property on a control within an xml manually. But it seems to be overwritten before rendering by a style property coming from the control itself.

Inspecting the element, I see the following html syntax `<div id="__xmlview0--vBoxCol1" data-sap-ui="__xmlview0--vBoxCol1" class="column sapMFlexBox sapMVBox" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column">...</div>` and my manually added `style="transition:2s;"` is no longer visible nor rendered. I was hoping that adding the style attribute would make animations possible without using css classes

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that under the hood the new layoutData invalidates the grid and it is re-rendered, thus there is no width recalculation. The whole DOM element is removed than added.